# Random empty spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Fixed / Solved

Thanks to @Steve this is the solution:

> I believe this is due to slightly different heights between the
>   individual boxes. Since they are all floated, a slightly taller first
>   box, would make the first box in the second row start AFTER the extra
>   space the first box occupies.
>
> Make sure they are all forced to have the exact same height.

---

### Question

I have no idea why this is happening - Suddenly the site I am developing for started to have these weird spaces appear? (The Red box has been added to s

Any Idea why this would be happening or how to fix it? It is not just in this one place, I am building another page that is randomly adding a blank space as well?

If I change the `max-width` property on the images, every other pixel will put the out-of-place one back into place?

I am viewing with

**Chrome/Firefox/Safari**: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31`

[image: odd happenings]

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span12" style="margin-top: -15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="span10" style="margin: 0px auto; float: none;">
        <a href="/news-and-media"><img src="" alt="Magazines and blogs" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <a href="/how-to-use"><img src="" alt="How to use" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <a href="/store"><img src="" alt="Products" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <a href="/endorsements"><img src="" alt="Endorsements" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <a href="/before-after"><img src="" alt="Before and After" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <a href="/doctor-recommended"><img src="" alt="Doctor Recomended" class="span3 front-page-tile pull-left"></a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could it be that the first box (with the red text inside) is slightly taller than the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to slightly different heights between the individual boxes. Since they are all floated, a slightly taller first box, would make the first box in the second row start AFTER the extra space the first box occupies.

Make sure they are all forced to have the exact same height.

Comment: Wow - I have never had this happen before. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this style to your style sheet.

```
.span10 a{vertical-align: top;}
```

Or if you want to continue to use inline-stlyes, add style="vertical-align: top;" to each of your anchors.

Comment: Good call... I just saw that all the images are exactly the same height, so my answer is probably incorrect.  But I have seen this exact issue before being caused by `vertical-align`.

Comment: Try changing your display to "display: inline-block;" in addition to the vertical align.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as I can't currently see your CSS but have you tried using `display:inline-block;` (`zoom:1;*display:inline;` - fix for older versions of IE) for your links?

Comment: What am I applying it to? I am using TwitterBootstrap so this shouldn't be a problem?