# There are some random empty spaces between multiple divs due to different heights. How can I get rid of them without using forced height?

Tags: html, css, containers, prestashop

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820397/random-empty-spaces) pertaining to my issue and the solution to it is to have a forced height. However, this is causing issues with the responsiveness of the theme. Let me explain.

I'm using Prestashop with [this theme](http://iqit-commerce.com/ps162/demo7/en/3-women). As you can see, the images used in the demo are quite tall (395 x **468**px). My product images does not have this much height (they're around 355 x **240**px) and this is causing the issue with the random empty spaces between them. I've made some modifications to the original and currently, it kind of looks like the following:

[image]

Now, I was able to achieve a temporary fix by forcing a height of 400px on `<div class="product-container">` inside `<li class="ajax_block_product>`:

```
ul.product_list.grid > li .product-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
```

However, this is not quite effective as it created some problems with the responsiveness of the theme. In tablet/mobile/other screen views the height of 400px is either not enough or it's too much. When the height is not enough, elements inside the container are overflowing and when it's too much there is a huge gap between the divs (height wise).

For this I made another sloppy fix by adding `@media` rules for `product-container` and added different heights such as 300px, 380px and 420px. I feel like this is not very practical and there is a better solution that I'm not seeing. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me the problem is not the fact that your image are shorter but probably the fact that not all of your product images are the same height. The only way (I know of) is to indeed have all the product containers be the same height, which may be achieved by having your images the same height. Not accounting for the fact that this theme won't be visually pleasing if all your product containers are different heights.

Comment: @JiFus It seems like you are absolutely correct. Prestashop has a function to regenerate images to user's specified dimensions and by the looks of it, it's not working correctly. I undid the fix of having a forced height on `product-container` and did an inspect element to see the natural heights on each container. Some containers have a height difference of 1px than the rest. I'll try fiddling with the regeneration settings to get this to work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: see masonry.desandro.com

Comment: @RonRoyston Woah, that's awesome. I will try it out as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and simple solution would be to use flexbox with wrapping (on the container), like

```
ul.product_list.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution in regards to this besides having a forced height on `product-container` is to make all the images to have the exact same height. In my response to @JiFus I mentioned this:

> I undid the fix of having a forced height on product-container and did
>   an inspect element to see the natural heights on each container. Some
>   containers have a height difference of 1px than the rest.

Prestashop has an option to regenerate images in specified dimensions so I will simply mess around with the settings in hopes of getting it to work correctly.